# Scraping a redirected site using requests and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am using `requests` and `BeautifulSoup4` to scrape a NBA website.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get('http://www.nba.com/games/20111225/BOSNYK/boxscore.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
```

The url to the site actually leads to 'http://www.nba.com/games/20111225/BOSNYK/gameinfo.html#nbaGIboxscore' when it is entered into a browser and I thought that using `requests` is the proper way of simulating this.

The trouble is I don't know the keywords of this effect and having trouble finding the solutions online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `regex` or `bs4` in order to find the redirected site and then use `requests` in order to scrape him.

For example:

```
import bs4
import requests

original_url = 'http://www.nba.com/games/20111225/BOSNYK/'
old_suffix = 'boxscore.html'
r = requests.get(original_url + old_suffix)
site_content = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
meta = site_content.find_all('meta')[0]
meta_content = meta.attrs.get('content')
new_suffix = meta.attrs.get('content')[6:]
new_url_to_scrape = original_url + new_suffix
```

And then scrape the `new_url_to_scarpe`.
Enjoy!

Comment: Nice, I see now!